# Sync both Android sqlite db and GAE datastore

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-app-engine, synchronization

I'm developing an Android app it stores the data in GAE data-store it's working fine all CRUD operations when user is in online.Now I'm storing data in offline mode also, my problem is how to maintain the sync between the both mobile db and GAE data-store.please can anyone explain me how to resolve the sync problem or even provide some tutorials or samples.

Answer (score 1):

Its complex, mostly depending on how you change your gae db. Easiest way is to have a lastUpdated field in your db entities that is always updated when you create or update entities (but when deleting you need to do something more complex like another table that remembers what you deleted).

On the android side you have a query based on that field. The query can even be kept alive as a continuous query (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Cursors_and_data_updates) so you will quickly see new/modified fields without having to execute the query again.